# предложение По обучению или об обучении

Tags: лексика, лексикография

Скажите, пожалуйста, как правильно написать: предложение по обучению или предложение об обучении сотрудников?

Answer (score 2):

Оба варианта возможны.

1. Предложение **об обучении сотрудников**.  Это предложение  о том, чтобы начать обучать сотрудников, то есть задание самой темы обучения.
2. Предложение **по обучению сотрудников**.  Это предложение относительно уже существующей темы, то есть разработка конкретных деталей проекта.